# Como esse código pode ser melhorado? Ele lida bem com exceções?

Tags: c#, exceção, parse, entrada-de-dados, controle-de-fluxo

Estava praticando C# e minha lógica e criei um programa que cria uma tabuada do número inserido, de 0 a 10. A lógica em si é simples e não vi nenhum erro. O que me interessa é saber se o código pode ser melhorado e se minha abordagem pra lidar com inserções não numéricas está boa. Primeiro eu estava usando o Convert.ToInt32, que sempre retorna 0 caso o usuário insira uma string ou char. Pesquisei e descobri o int.TryParse e criei um if statment. Também botei tudo dentro de um loop while, pro programa se repetir sem ter fechar e abrir ele novamente.

Obs.: Não sei o termo correto é exceções nesse caso.

```
while (true)
{
    Console.Clear();
    Console.WriteLine("Digite um número inteiro: ");
    int numero;
    bool isValidNumber = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out numero); // Verificar se o TryParse foi bem sucedido

    if (isValidNumber)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            int resultado = numero * i;
            Console.WriteLine($"\t {numero} x {i} = {resultado}");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Pressione qualquer tecla para começar novamente ou 'q' para sair.");
        var key = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
        if (key == 'q')
        {
            break; // Sair do loop while
        }
    }

    else //Em caso de inserção de um valor não válido
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Valor inválido! Aperte qualquer tecla para voltar.");
        Console.ReadKey(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Uma exceção geralmente é um evento que desvia o programa para um local especial chamado "bloco de tratamento de exceção", que em geral fica abaixo do bloco de código onde a exceção está sujeita a ocorrer. Seu código não tem nenhum tratamento desse tipo (o que está correto, pois nenhuma situação com a qual o programa está lidando pode ser considerada excepcional; o usuário pode ou não digitar um número corretamente, pode ou não querer sair do programa - são fluxos normais).

Comment: Já um esquecimento que leve o programa a tentar usar uma variável não-inicializada pode causar o lançamento de uma exceção, e o programador pode querer capturar esta exceção preventivamente para evitar que o programa termine prematuramente.

Comment: Ah, entendi. É que eu não sei dizer o nome quando um usuário insere algo que o programa não estava esperando. Eu associei o noem exceção por metonímia, pois é o que o ocorre quando a gente faz de jeito diferente

Comment: Aí são diferentes situações em que os mecanismos de controle de fluxo são utilizados. Não pense como entradas excepcionais, apenas inválidas (uma entrada ser inválida é uma situação comum, e sujeita a ser tratada mediante uma validação). Não me lembro de nomes específicos para elas. A condição `key == 'q'` pode ser chamada de condição de saída do laço. Também cláusulas de guarda são uma forma de programar situações como a da checagem de entrada numérica válida. Mas logo passa alguém mais versado em linguagem C# e programação em geral e me corrige se tiver falado besteira ou esquecido algo.

Answer (score -2):

Sua abordagem para lidar com inserções não numéricas usando int.TryParse() é uma boa prática. Isso permite que você verifique se a conversão do valor de entrada para um número inteiro foi bem sucedida ou não, sem lançar uma exceção no caso de entrada inválida. Utilizar um bool para armazenar o resultado da conversão e, em seguida, usar um if para verificar se o valor é válido ou não, é uma maneira eficiente de lidar com esse tipo de situação.

Além disso, envolver o código em um loop while (true) para permitir que o programa continue sendo executado até que o usuário escolha sair é uma abordagem válida para manter o programa em execução e permitir múltiplas iterações sem ter que reiniciar o programa a cada vez.

Uma possível melhoria é adicionar uma mensagem de erro mais informativa quando o valor inserido não for válido. Por exemplo, em vez de apenas exibir "Valor inválido! Aperte qualquer tecla para voltar.", você pode fornecer uma mensagem mais específica, como "O valor inserido não é um número inteiro válido. Por favor, tente novamente." Isso pode ajudar o usuário a entender o motivo do erro e corrigir a entrada de forma adequada.

Outra possível melhoria é usar Console.Clear() antes de exibir a mensagem de erro, para limpar a tela e tornar a mensagem mais visível. Isso pode melhorar a experiência do usuário, tornando mais fácil para ele identificar o erro e corrigi-lo.

Por último, é sempre bom adicionar um tratamento de erro mais robusto para lidar com possíveis exceções que possam ser lançadas durante a execução do programa, por exemplo, se o usuário pressionar CTRL+C para interromper a execução do programa. Você pode usar um bloco try-catch para capturar exceções não tratadas e fornecer uma mensagem de erro apropriada para o usuário, em vez de simplesmente fechar o programa abruptamente.

No geral, sua abordagem está boa, mas você pode considerar algumas melhorias adicionais para tornar o programa mais robusto e amigável para o usuário.

Comment: Obrigada. Só não entendo por que o povo desse site tem mania de ficar dndo downvote e sequer fazer explicação melhor nem nada do tipo.